# Easy ways to setup or pair IoT devices

Tags: smart-home, aws-iot

I am intending to create a user-friendly and easy way for the users to be able to pair the phone application with an access point with also pairs into an electricity meter.. between the meter and access point the communication is through RF / OMS, between the access point and phone its Wifi, but access point has NFC also.. so am looking at an easy  way to pair them which won't frustrate the user..eg can use NFC tag, or serial number, or voice command please suggest

Comment: Can your "access point" actually act as a WiFi client? Does it support BLE? Does the user need to get access on a regular basis? Does the "access point" need Internet access (e.g. for remote management, uploading data to a server, connecting to it while not at home...)?

Comment: Sony cameras have tried this and gotten it to work with NFC well with Android. The iPhone NFC is different and doesnt seem to work. They've resorted to having the user actually goto settings and connect to wifi. I'll be interested to see you can make it work.